# How to get Office 2010 (specifically Outlook) to run?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

Although there are many alternatives out there, I'm not prepared to get away from Outlook yet, and I have many clients I'd like to switch over to Ubuntu but they need Outlook and won't switch because of this one thing holding them back.

Currently I have Ubuntu 11.10, Wine 1.3.35 and PlayOnLinux 4.0.14
I tried to get Wine 1.3.9 which apparently supports Office 2010 but I can't get that to install either.  Not sure if it's a waste of time, but that's a separate question if it's a path worth going down.

Office 2010 starts install with PlayOnLinux no problem but half way through fails with the following error:

```
1: 25541 2: -2147024786 3:
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
```

I'm thinking I have to install .NET framework separately first but I don't want to mindlessly install all kinds of software and makes things worse.  I appreciate any advice on this so I can help promote this awesome operating system.

Comment: Did you follow any instructions at the appdb.winehq.org site?.

Comment: According to winehq it will not work : http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=34 If outlook is that mission critical perhaps stay with windows. Is there some feature in outlook that does not work with the linux native alternates ? I am not trying to tell you what to do, merely suggesting it may be easier to migrate to a linux alternate then maintain outlook in wine/playonlinux, and having outlook fail would not be good either.

Comment: Welcome To AskUbuntu! Office 2010 is not very well supported under Wine :( . I suggest you use thunderbird or Outlook 2003 :D . Most of the Outlook Features are on Native linux clients. If it is really required... You'd be needing the windows :D

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I know there are alternatives, but I'd like to work with the Ubuntu community to find a way to make it work so more people will want to switch over from Windows.  I'm ok with changing to Thunderbird probably, but then there are issues like how to sync my Blackberry with it when it only has the option for Outlook?  That's another question for another time.  Some websites like Bodhi.zazen found say it doesn't work,but others like heiko81 found says it does work with some tweaks.  There's several scenarios which I'd like to address, I'm going through one at a time.

Comment: I found that using Wine 1.5 got outlook 2010 to install properly, but it still seems to crash almost immediately after it downloads the inbox.

Comment: I also got outlook 2010 to install but it keps crashing after n seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32-bit version of Microsoft Office should be installable through Wine, as they refer in their site in Ubuntu 11.10; so please follow their instruction and be sure you have a version of Wine above 1.3.35. There is also a trick to solve your problem about the file machine.config.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336

Comment: Thanks heiko81.  I tried this and I'm having problems with installing the msxml6.  It flashes on the screen and then disappears.  In the list of DLLs to install, it says "cached" for the status.  New issue!  :(  Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: You have to start Winetricks (you can find it easily searching in the Unity Lens) and then choose Select the default wineprefix, Install a Windows DLL or component, and then install the msxml6 package. I've just tried and it works.

Comment: Ya, that's what I tried and it doesn't have the check mark on showing it is installed, but it also says "cached" in the status.  So I'm not sure how or if I can uninstall it to try again.  I think I really screwed it up somehow.  I'll see what else I can do in the mean time.

Comment: OK, I got Office 2010 to successfully do a full install.  Only problem, which I was suspecting, is Outlook won't run.  I get the following error...
Error: Binary not found! :OUTLOOK.EXE  Have you installed the program to the default location?  Thanks for helping me successfully install Office 2010.  I just need to spend more time playing around and researching.

Comment: If anyone is interested how I installed Office 2010 Pro edition...  I used PlayOnLinux.  I clicked to install program not listed.  I choose the libraries to install during installation.  msxml6 and dotnet20.  Couldn't find Core fonts in that list.  Go through prompts and it eventually finishes successfully.

Comment: You can find the core fonts in winetricks where there is an option "Install a font".

Comment: After multiple failures, I came out with this success: http://blog.z-proj.com/microsoft-office-2010-professional-pro-on-wine-1-6/

Answer (score 1):

All windows MS Office apps will install and work on Ubuntu if you use Crossover.  Outlook does have some issues IF you, like me wish to use gmail and IMAP.  This is because of the TSL and SSL security it, gmail, requires.  STUNNEL(4) is supposed to resolve these problems as it acts as a middleware server, but I have yet to make it work.

So, yes, I have mine up and running, but as I use gmail and IMAP I can not get it to sync on inbox.